# Import Statements in ES6 from MDN docs

Tags: javascript

I was going through [Firefox import statements.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

They have shown certain import statement like this

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

But haven't added example to help differentiate between some and their example is also sort of vague.

From the docs, There are multiple things which doesn't make sense to me.. for example how is **name** different from  **defaultExport**

While default export does make sense to me, the defination of name is sort of difficult to comprehend

Explanation given by them:

> The name parameter is the name of the "module object" which will be
>   used as a kind of namespace to refer to the exports.

From the above syntax: `import "module-name";`

Second:

```
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
```

Also, if suppose we have multiple function which we need to export

```
function abc1 () {
}

function abc2 () {
}
```

Will this be the correct way to export?

```
export abc1;
export abc2;
```

And then if we import, how would we attach variable to it? Is this where statement like this come in?

```
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
```

Comment: Do you actually mean `import { abc1 as alias } from "module-name";`?

Comment: About the first point: instead of calling a function (for example) using `export.foo()`, with an `alias `specified through `as` keyword, you will access it using `alias.foo()`.

Comment: Second point: if you need to import `abc1` and `abc2`, then one way (without aliasing) is: `import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";`

Comment: Advice: usually you can find a lot more in *See Also* section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#See_also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this module `module-name`:

```js
// module-name.js
export default function foo(){ console.log("foo");}
export function bar(){ console.log("bar");}
console.log("hello world");
```

Consider the following cases which have been tested in node.js v9.11.1 using the command `node --experimental-modules some-importer.mjs`:

---

#### Importing the `default export`

```js
// import defaultExport from "module-name";
import fizzbuzz from "module-name";
```

Only the default export will be available thus:

- `fizzbuzz` (which is `foo`) is available
- `bar` is **not** available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

---

#### Importing all exports using `*` wildcard

```js
import * as name from "module-name";
```

All exports are available but attached to an Object identified as `name`:

- `foo` is **not** available
- `bar` is **not** available
- `name.foo` is **not** available (though you think it would be)
- `name.bar` is available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

---

#### Importing an identified export

```js
// import { export } from "module-name";
import { bar } from "module-name"
```

Only the identified export is available:

- `foo` is **not** available
- `bar` is available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

---

#### Importing an identified export as an alias

```js
// import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { bar as mybar } from "module-name";
```

Only the identified export is available and only **as** the identified alias:

- `foo` is **not** available
- `bar` is **not** available
- `mybar` (which is `bar`) is available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

---

#### Importing the `default export` and using the `*` wildcard

```js
// import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import fizzbuzz, * as name from "module-name";
```

The default item from the module can be referenced as `defaultExport` and all other exported items are attached to `name`

- `fizzbuzz` (which is `foo`) is available
- `bar` is **not** available
- `name.bar` is available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

---

#### No actual identified imports

```js
import "module-name";
```

The module is loaded, but nothing is actually available in the module that imported.  This means that file runs but nothing is exposed

- `foo` is **not** available
- `bar` is **not** available
- `console.log(hello world)` will have been run

Comment: That’s a great, comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

> how is `name` different from `defaultExport`?

`name` is an object that holds all the exported values as exported key/values, except for the default export, which will be in `defaultExport`. If you would export the following from a file:

```
export default function main() {}
export function helper1() {}
export function helper2() {}
```

Then you could import `main` as the default import:

```
import main from "file";
```

That won't import the helpers. For that you would use `* as`:

```
import * as helpers from "file";
helpers.helper1();
```

> And then if we import, how would we attach variable to it?

They get attached to the same name they were exported with, so to only import one of the above helpers:

```
import { helper1 } from "file";
helper1();
```

If you want to rename that import because it is missleading / clashing, then the `as` syntax comes in:

```
import { helper1 as someOther } from "file";
someOther();
```