# imported functions don't work under render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to move a bunch of reusable functions into a convenient place, but I'm having issues with using them in other files. I am using a static React.js frontend without Node.

miscFunctions.js

```
export const capitalize = (string) => {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

module.exports = {
  capitalize,
  other functions...
}
```

Test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import capitalize from './miscFunctions';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.capitalize = capitalize.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.capitalize("foo")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

capitalize() works just fine so long as it's used in a class function, but once  I try to use it within render(), it doesn't exist. I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

Comment: Why put the `capitalize` function on the component at all? Remove it from the constructor and just write `{capitalize("foo")}`. It's also a named export, so you need to import it like `import { capitalize } from './miscFunctions'; `

Comment: I think you should import like `import {capitalize} from './miscFunctions';` though. That could be the problem.

Comment: You have a mistake in your code as Kubwimana pointed out.  See my answer to the differences between various `imports`: [Import Statements in ES6 from MDN docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51215965/691711).

Comment: Yes, I have tried a few different way of getting this function to work as intended. When I change it to `{capitalize}` and remove the binding, I get a compile time error "Attempted import error: 'capitalize' is not exported from './miscFunctions'."

Comment: @anthony You don't need both `export const capitalize` and `module.exports = { capitalize, ... }`. Try removing `module.exports` and see what happens.

Comment: All right, I have removed it, but that doesn't appear to have changed anything. I still get that "'capitalize' is not exported".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the `capitalize` function on the component at all. You can remove it from the constructor and just use it as is.

`capitalize` is a named export, so you need to import it with that in mind.

```
// miscFunctions.js
export const capitalize = (string) => {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

```
// Test.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { capitalize } from './miscFunctions';

class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {capitalize("foo")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: This was one of my iterations of trying to import the function properly. The code looks like i would expect, but I get an error saying that "'capitalize' is not exported from './miscFunctions'." But as far as I can tell, it is.

Comment: @anthony That's frustrating. [It should work fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvq86v97py). Have you tried removing `module.exports = { ... };` entirely? You don't need both `export const capitalize` and `module.exports = { capitalize, ... }`