# React Import Modules using best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In your experience what's the best practice when importing large modules into your component. Could you please tell me which and the reason why from the example below?

```
import * from './foo'
```

or

```
import {bar, beer, brew } from './foo'
```

Comment: The question of which to use is opinion based.  And the question of what the differences are is potentially a duplicate of this question: [Import Statements in ES6 from MDN docs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51215691/691711).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import * as name from './foo'` will import everything from `foo`, but the second statement will only import three exports from the module.

It's very context specific, but in my opinion it's much easier to see what is actually imported in the second example, and you will also be able to take advantage of [`tree shaking`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) if e.g. not all exports from a library are used.