# Casting a class type and calling a static property

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm working in a javascript project using [jsdoc/typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc) validation and having trouble casting a type, and using a static property of it afterwards.

When using an imported type I have the below problem:

```
// @ts-check -- foo.js
export default class Foo {
    static bar() {}
}
```

```
// @ts-check -- bar.js

/** @typedef {import('./foo').default} Foo */

const HopefullyFoo = /** @type {unknown} */ ('Foo');

const foo = /** @type {typeof Foo} */ (HopefullyFoo);

foo.bar();
```

Output:

```
src/components/bar.js:7:31 - error TS2693: 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

7 const foo = /** @type {typeof Foo} */ (HopefullyFoo);
                                ~~~
```

If I put everything in one file it seems ok:

```
// @ts-check

class Foo {
    static bar() {}
}

const LikelyFoo = /** @type {unknown} */ ('Foo');

const foo = /** @type {typeof Foo} */ (LikelyFoo);

foo.bar();

// No errors
```

If I don't cast to typeof I get this error so I don't think that's right either.

```
// @ts-check

class Foo {
    static bar() {

    }
}

const LikelyFoo = Foo;

const foo = /** @type {Foo} */ (LikelyFoo);

foo.bar();
```

Output

```
src/components/foo.js:13:5 - error TS2576: Property 'bar' is a static member of type 'Foo'

13 foo.bar();
       ~~~
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand why you feel the need to annotate these, for simply stuff the compiler can usually infer the types. But your problem is your import statement. It's not clear whether you are trying to import the default from a module, or use the new import function to lazy load one, but either way you're doing it wrong, please go see the relevant documentation on mdn. [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Statements in ES6 from MDN docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215691/import-statements-in-es6-from-mdn-docs)

Comment: @JaredSmith The import is [JSDoc/Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc)-ism, it's not a standard import like you linked

Comment: [Not seeing anything like that here...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html)

Comment: @JaredSmith Look for the example containing "import("./a").Pet" on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type of a class is a type that an object created by the constructor of this class will have. This type contains only instance level fields, that is why you correctly uses `typeof` operator. The problem is that the operator cannot be applied to type, instead it needs a value. 
In case of usual import

```
import Foo from "./foo";
```

you get both the type and the value (constructor) but in case of jsdoc import you get a type only.
So if you cannot import the real value for some reason you may add an alias for `typeof Foo` next to the class definition:

foo.js

```
// @ts-check -- foo.js
export default class Foo {
  static bar() {}
}
/** @typedef {typeof Foo} FooCtor */
```

and use it then

```
// @ts-check -- bar.js

/** @typedef {import('./foo').FooCtor} FooCtor */

const HopefullyFoo = /** @type {unknown} */ ('Foo');

const foo = /** @type {FooCtor} */ (HopefullyFoo);

foo.bar();
```

PS: tbh, I've never seen uses TS this way, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank works! Thanks... would never had figured that out on my own.